# What port does IIS 7 use to connect to another IIS server?

Tags: port, iis

I'm trying to connect to another IIS server and I know the windows firewall is turned on on both servers.  I'd like to be able to create an allow rule, but what port does IIS 7 use to connect to another IIS server?

Sorry, let me be more specific.  Using the IIS manager to connect to another IIS server.

Comment: Can you give more details.  I would guess port 80

Comment: Are you talking about communication between 2 sites, or are you talking about using the iis management console on one machine to connect to another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about Remote Administration (connect to another server using IIS Manager to manage it), then the answer is **port 8172** by default using SSL. That of course can be changed on the server using the Management Service UI inside IIS Manager.